# How to make JSON response with URL endpoint from 3rd party site

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I have some problem with sync data from other site to my site with JSON response. I got the documentation from the other site to push some data to my site. The documentation said if I must create URL endpoint and make JSON response to get the data. This is the JSON response format I got form the documentation :

```
{
  "id": INTEGER, // Confirmation Number
  "type": STRING, // "new" or "update" or "cancel"
  "data": OBJECT // data element
}
```

In this case my site is using `Codeigniter` framework. Which I want to ask is how to make that JSON response in my site ? I have already create some function in `Controller` like this :

```
function json_response()
{

}
```

And I don't know what codes I must put in that `Controller`. Thanks.

Comment: *how to make that JSON response in my site?* or how to make request to that site to get the JSOn data?

Comment: @SougataBose I this case the other site push the data to my site using JSON. The step is I give URL endpoint to other site and that site call the URL and push the data with JSON.

Answer (score 1):

If you not sure on what variable name they send JSON data, try to var_dump the $_POST variable to some table in your database or write the $_POST variable values into a file.  By doing that, you could inspect what are the variables you got on that request.